# Change "Try PayPal as a Guest" to "Pay with a debit or credit card" in Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: paypal

Is there a way to change "Try PayPal as a Guest" to "Pay with a debit or credit card" in Paypal Express Checkout?

As I read in reference:

> Browser cookies determine Checkout view The buyer's checkout view on
>   PayPal depends on their web browser's cookies:
>
> - If a PayPal cookie has been created: When the buyer lands on a PayPal page, they'll see the PayPal Login but still have the option to
>     select "Try Paypal as a Guest"?
> - If a PayPal cookie hasn't been defined: The buyer sees a default view of Guest Checkout allowing for debit or credit payment: "Pay with
>     Debit or Credit Card"

Is it possible to leave only "Pay with a debit or credit card"?

Answer (score 1):

Regrettably its not possible to leave only "Pay with a debit or credit card" at PayPal checkout page. PayPal server will determine the options dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You can change with this simple input field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="landing_page" value="billing">
```

Its 100% works for me. I hope it will be work for you.

Complete Paypal Payment Form:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="yourbusinesspaypalaccountemail@mail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Your Item Name">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="YOUR TOTAL AMOUNT">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="landing_page" value="billing"> <!-- This filed redirect to Billing Page -->
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="Your Success URL">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="Your Cancel Return URL">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="image" src="https://www.yourdomain.com/images/paypalpaynowbtn.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.yourdomain.com/images/paypalpaynowbtn.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```